Get IDENTITY from source table and change not null of date while using select * into staging_table from table
I have a requirement where there are two main table involved one is staging table - DLSTYTOTAL data coming from other source RDBMS and another table is partitioned table -STYTOTAL_RAW where we are loading the incoming data.

Auto generate next identity value from source partitioned  table

To do partition, I have created one more staging table called - STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging. Since  DLSTYTOTAL table does not have all the columns particularly identity column and partition key columns.
The main staging table gets 10 million + data. I thought of using select * into with each time drop and create it the partition staging table then switch to partition table. The problem is I could not get the correct IDENTITY value since it reset each time. I thought of taking the max value plus 1 from partition table - STYTOTAL_RAW. But select IDENTITY(INT,@IDENTITY_no_max ,1) AS [STYTOTALID] this is not accepting variable
declare @IDENTITY_no_max bigint
select  max([STYTOTALID]) as [Original_max] from STYTOTAL_RAW -- original max value
select @IDENTITY_no_max= max([STYTOTALID]+1) from STYTOTAL_RAW
select @IDENTITY_no_max as [@IDENTITY_no_max]
    
select IDENTITY(INT,1,@IDENTITY_no_max) AS [STYTOTALID],ISNULL([STYLE],0) [STYLE],DATEADD(MICROSECOND, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), SYSDATETIME()) [InsertedDateTime],
CAST(1 AS bit)  as [IsCurrent],[DELDATTIM],[DELFLAG]
into [STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging] from [C1810429].[DLSTYTOTAL]


Change date clolumn [InsertedDateTime] to not null from the select * into itself.
select DATEADD(MICROSECOND, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL)), isnull(SYSDATETIME(),'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000') ) [InsertedDateTime]
into tbl_date_not_null
sp_help 'tbl_date_not_null'


Is there any way to get the identity value all the time from source table and populate to staging . Also is it possible to change the date column into not null in the select * into itself instead of alter table with not null.
Thank you for your help.
Adding the script here: https://dbfiddle.uk/uaMhsB4k

Example for the identity column STYTOTALID if I check value 1 that comes 3 times because of initial data and two load. I also alter the table and adding not null manually. I could not invoke in select * into itself

I think the 1st question is - How to get a sequence value which like IDENTITY but with specific start value. If my understanding is correct, and the values are generated only by you, you can try using Sequence Numbers.
The 2nd question, why not use CRAETE TABLE and INSERT INTO... SELECT...

Hi @Rodger Kong, Yes your understanding is correct. I tested with 100 million data the insert into took almost 30 minutes and select * into plus creating not null constraint and primary key all together took 5 minutes. I will test with your suggestion.

You can try table hint, INSERT INTO [target_table] WITH (TABLOCK)... SELECT ... FROM [source_table] WITH(NOLOCK)
